# Sync GET using Request library in Node

Tags: node.js, express, request, pug

I would like to get data from an api to return to my Jade page.

How do I make the GET request be synchronous so the render waits until it has the data?

Here is my API Service:

```
var request = require('request');
var constants = require('../config/constants');

var service = {
    get: function (url) {
        url = constants.API.URL + url;

        return request(url, function (error, response, body) {
            return JSON.parse(body);
        });
    }
}

module.exports = service;
```

Here is how I am using it:

```
var api = require('./api');

var service = {
    list: function (success) {
        return api.get('companies');
    },
    names: function () {
        return api.get('companies/names');
    }
};

module.exports = service;
```

And here is my controller:

```
var controller = function (app) {
    var companyService = require('../services/companies');

    app.get('/companies', function (req, res, next) {
        return res.render('companies', { title: 'Companies', companies: companyService.list() });
    });
};

module.exports = controller;
```

Edit: Ok, understanding that this is a bad idea makes sense. My real issue is my middleware for getting companies and adding them to every page:

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    var companyService = require('../services/companies');

    if (req.method === 'GET') {
        if (!req.session.companies) {
            req.session.companies = companyService.names();
        }

        if (!req.session.companies) {
            res.redirect('/logout');
        }

        if (!req.session.currentCompany) {
            req.session.currentCompany = req.session.companies[0];
        }

        res.locals.companies = req.session.companies;
        res.locals.currentCompany = req.session.currentCompany;
    }

    next();
}
```

app.js

```
app.use(companiesMiddleware);
```

How do I prevent this from loading the page until the companies are loaded so it adds them to a selection list at the top? Do I put next() in the callback?

There are only a few companies so saving it in a session isn't going to affect performance, and I will most likely use a cache later anyways to speed it up more. So this is just for how to execute this on every page load.

Comment: *"How do I make the GET request be synchronous"* This is a very bad idea. Every time someone requests /companies, all future requests to the server will be delayed until the /companies request completes. You'll want to instead properly use asynchronous methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pass a callback function to your api, which will contain rendering of the page. You can do it like this:

*Api service:*

```
var service = {
    get: function (url, success) {
        url = constants.API.URL + url;

        return request(url, function (error, response, body) {
            var result = JSON.parse(body);
            success(result);
        });
    }
}
```

*Your service:*

```
var service = {
    list: function (success) {
        return api.get('companies', success);
    },
    names: function (success) {
        return api.get('companies/names', success);
    }
};
```

*You controller:*

```
app.get('/companies', function (req, res, next) {
    companyService.list(function(companies) {
        return res.render('companies', { title: 'Companies', companies: companies });
    });        
});
```

If you are going to request the service multiple times per request (e.g. to get companies, users, etc), then I suggest you to look at [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) library to save you from `callback hell`.

PS: making the request synchronous is a really **bad idea**. Not only it doesn't go well with the ideas that node.js stands on, it will affect performance of your web application.

Comment: The async library looks good. I will definitely use that. But I just edited my code to show the real issue, which is needing companies pre page load for all pages. How would I do that without waiting?

Comment: You can load all the companies before starting the server and cache them (there are plenty caching libraries or you can do it on your own)